# Relative imports and initialization exceptions

Tags: python

I'm trying to deal with a situation where package `foo` performs a relative import of subpackage `foo.bar`, but then raises an exception itself before the initialization of `foo` is complete. In this situation, `foo` is not imported, so `reload(foo)` won't work. But `import foo` fails on the relative import line, `ImportError: cannot import name 'bar'`.

In a case where this is simply a bug in the package, obviously I can just quit my interpreter, fix the bug, and move on. But I'm using this in cases where the problem may be due to an issue in the user's environment, and they could fix it and want to reload without restarting the interpreter (assuming they're working in an interactive session.)

Contrived example, the random() is just there to provide some reason to try a reload/reimport:

```
#foo/__init__.py
from . import bar
bar.init()

#foo/bar.py
import random
import time

def init():
    random.seed(time.time())
    if random.random() >= 0.5:
        raise ValueError
```

The only workaround I've come up with is to trap the exception (allow the import to succeed) and have some sort of proxy object that manages the not-initialized case.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you could try deleting `foo` from `sys.modules` (with `del sys.modules['foo']`), and maybe the same for `foo.bar` as well.

Comment: That's probably a reasonable way to go, as most of the pitfalls of fandangoing on ``sys.modules`` shouldn't apply here (pretty sure of what's going on, etc.) Just removing ``foo`` appears to do the job. Thanks. (But please do ask if there are specifics I can do to make the question clearer!)